# how to scrape aka display all contents of an excel document in vb6

Tags: excel, vb6

i made a program to read an excel document and display it on a messageBox. but, the thing is, i want to scrap aka display all of it to messageBox without knowing which row or column to choose. i wrote this code:

```
  Private Sub Command1_Click()
  On Error GoTo Err

  StartExcel

  Set ExcelWBk = Excel.Workbooks.Open(App.Path & "\Dataku.xls")
  Set ExcelWS = ExcelWBk.Worksheets(1)
  With ExcelWS

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strData As String

    For i = 1 To 5

      strData = strData & .Cells(i, 1) & vbCrLf
    Next i
  End With

  MsgBox strData
  CloseWorkSheet
  ClearExcelMemory
  Exit Sub
Err:
  ClearExcelMemory 
End Sub
```

but it returned into datas of that column (column 1) only. i need to read whole excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (tested in PowerPoint as I dont have VB6) will get the  `UsedRange` of the first sheet cell by cell (using an array for efficiency)

Pls change your file path to suit.

**First version - tested in PowerPoint**

```
Sub GetData()
Dim objExcel As Object
Dim objWB As Object
Dim objws As Object
Dim X As Variant
Dim lngCol As Long
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim strOut As String


Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
On Error Resume Next
Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("c:\temp\test.xlsx")
Set objws = objWB.Sheets(1)
On Error GoTo 0
If objws Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'recalc usedrange
objws.usedrange
X = objws.usedrange
For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
    For lngCol = 1 To UBound(X, 2)
        strOut = strOut & (X(lngRow, lngCol) & vbNewLine)
    Next
Next

objWB.Close False
objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
If Len(strOut) > 0 Then MsgBox strOut
End Sub
```

**VBS version**

```
Dim objExcel
Dim objWB
Dim objws 
Dim X
Dim lngCol
Dim lngRow
Dim strOut  

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
On Error Resume Next 
Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("c:\temp\test.xlsx") 
Set objws = objWB.Sheets(1) 
On Error GoTo 0 
If IsEmpty(objws) Then Stop

'recalc usedrange 
objws.usedrange 
X = objws.usedrange 
For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1) 
    For lngCol = 1 To UBound(X, 2) 
        strOut = strOut & (X(lngRow, lngCol) & vbNewLine) 
    Next 
Next 

objWB.Close False 
objExcel.Quit 
Set objExcel = Nothing 
If Len(strOut) > 0 Then MsgBox strOut
```

Comment: it's just blink and nothing happen